# MongoDb document size is too large PhP.How to increase limit

Tags: php, mongodb, size, limit, gridfs

i want to save documents but it gives me size too large error.
I can not break data into multiple collection as it will not help me while searching and joining,

Is there a way that i can save array using gridFs and it is still searchable or increase the document size limit.

I store data into .txt files and am shifting to MongoDb.Txt files are not searchable and hence need to be parsed and then i have to search.
Please Help.

Comment: What are you saving in document? If document size is greater than 16 MB then mongo divides document

Comment: i am saving some text data.

Comment: If you want to search the content, then you will need to break up the text you store yourself. All GridFS storage is effectively stored as binary and is broken up into 16MB chunks for you. So unfortunately, for what you want you are better off breaking up the content yourself. Or use a dedicated search engine solution instead of MongoDB.